# Is there a way to send a continuous stream from a command output to a remote listener

Tags: bash, sockets, shell, unix, netcat

I'm using the netcat for unix.

when I run `python script.py &> logfile.txt` , it gets captured continuously.

To replicate this remotely, I tried `nc -l -p 8011` on the listener (client) and the following for the sender (host or server) :

1. `python script.py &> nc 127.0.0.1 8011`
2. `python script.py > nc 127.0.0.1 8011`
3. `nc 127.0.0.1 8011 < python script.py`

But nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: im just posting this an a comment since i cant reproduce it atm. i think the problem is that you use the greater-than sign (>), to redirect the output to a FILE, that would be right, but to redirect to a COMMAND you need to use a pipe(|), so try to pipe it from python to nc on the sender side, and redirect from the reciever to a file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

Receiver:

```
nc -l 8011 >logfile.txt
```

Sender:

```
python script.py 2>&1 | nc 127.0.0.1 8011
```

Make sure to run the receiver code first.

---

**EDIT**: In case you're not aware there's a lot of [different versions of netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Ports_and_reimplementations); they all accept slightly different arguments (e.g. `nc.traditional` on Debian wants `nc -l -p 1234` to listen on port 1234, whereas BSD `nc` (e.g. OS X) just wants `nc -l 1234` and `ncat` may throw an interesting error unless you use the `-4` flag if your host doesn't support IPv6) - read the man pages to find out what combination of options you actually want.

Comment: no benjie. I am trying to replicate the output redirection remotely.

Comment: in fact, I'd like to add here(since I've been studying nc for a few hours now), the options -q and -e are not universal for every flavor of netcat, infact mac doesn't even support -l. Anyway, this is not related to my question.

Comment: Mac OS X Lion supports `-l` :)

Comment: Comment for the changed answer - yes I have tried that. In fact, that was my first approach to capturing the content (piping), but that did not re-direct the output and showed it on the shell itself. Refer to this [ article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/58)

Comment: Again Benjie, I have Mac OS X Lion right now. But I did replicate -l using the 'port' version of nc and removing the /usr/bin version

Comment: Have you tried `python script.py 2>&1 | nc 127.0.0.1 8011` in case your script is outputting stuff on stderr?

Comment: That was it. Thanks. I did try stderr but did not pipe the stream properly. Perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect answer, with one slight modification: adding **-p** for "port"

Receiver:

```
nc -l -p 8011 >logfile.txt
```

I pulled in the nc help file ( nc -h) using your suggestion

Sender:

```
nc -h 2>&1 | nc 127.0.0.1 8011
```

I tried

```
nc -h > logfile.txt
nc -h >> logfile.txt
```

which never worked.

I'm running netcat for Windows 7 in 2 cmd.exe's

Thanks, again