# What would be the most efficient way to log a raspberry pi's data over ssh?

Tags: logging, ssh, raspberry-pi, file-transfer

I currently have a python script on a raspberry pi that creates a log file in the same directory while running, with important data that I would like to view in real time on my laptop (that I can ssh into the pi with).

Obviously I can view the log file on my laptop while ssh'd using a text editor, but it's not a real-time data stream.

Unfortunately while I have a decent amount of python experience, I don't know much about networking stuff, except that I could scp/rsync the file onto my computer but of course, that's not giving me a real time view of my log file either.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939023/netcat-is-there-a-way-to-send-a-continuous-stream-from-a-command-output-to-a-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tail is commonly used for this, `tail -f yourlogfile.log` will show the ten latest lines of the file and update on file change.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'd like to listen for the file before tailing it, but I'm not sure why my code isn't working: https://pastebin.com/UW7kLYTS it only gets into the loop after I disconnect from my pi

Comment: Take a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/392072/make-tail-wait-for-a-file-to-exist

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas spring to mind...

The Unix `syslog` facility allows distributed/remote logging. You would probably find a Python module, or you could just create a socket and send messages to the `syslogd` on your laptop. You could even send messages with `netcat` at a pinch. [Related article](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/412/syslog-sending-log-from-remote-servers-to-syslog-daemon/)

You could set up Redis on your laptop and use the Python Redis module to send time-tagged messages either to a queue or a sorted hash and write a small script to wait on the queue on your laptop. Messages could also be given a *"time to live"* or expiry time so the memory demands don't get too excessive. [Related article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/redis-time-series)

---

A simpler option might be to write your log to a file on your Raspberry Pi and then depending on the OS of your laptop, to share that directory via NFS or Samba with your laptop. You can then use the `follow` (`-f`) option of `tail` to see last few lines continuously updated:

```
tail -f output.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Netcat.

On local PC

```
nc -l 2000
```

On remote

```
tail -f filename | nc hostip 2000
```